# How to display results from database in each line with percentage

Tags: html, codeigniter, dreamweaver, photoshop

I am developing my first site with codeigniter,html, dreamweaver and photoshop.
I made feedback page and want display the result as all websites i see.
for example  [enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEfWn.jpg) 
 80% excellent with line
40% good     with line

how display this line ? with any tool?please.

Comment: you want to know, how to show that percentage bar in html?? or percentage calculation in php??

Comment: does this bar in html .i know the calculation but the bar itself doesn't know

Comment: you have the html code for percentage bar??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bootstrap for this,

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
    40% Complete (success)
  </div>
</div>
```

See Official [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress) and [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp) for more information.